# Double click on grid row and load it to iframe ext.net

Tags: iframe, grid, ext.net

I want to load the `grid column` to `iframe` window.
For example in Parent Window first column is operation type and the data is `RECV or DELV`, and when user `double click` the `grid row` it will `autoload` the `RECV or DELV` to the `iframe textbox` txtoperation.

I'm new in using this `iframe` and not sure if the load is possible.
Any help are very useful to me.Thank you

Comment: Yes it's possible, try to see that example: http://examples2.ext.net/#/Panel/Basic/IFrame_Communication/

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in various applications and I find it best not to marshal complex data between windows.  My strategy is to send nothing more then an update command to the javascript in the other frame and let the frame manage it's own update strategy.

1. User Selects Row on Grid
2. DirectEvent back to server with Grid Selection (update database or session)
3. Direct Event On Success="updateAllWindows()"

Javascript:

```
var updateAllWindows = function(){
     foreach(var ii in window.frames){
         window.frames[ii].frameElement.contentWindow.updateFunction(); 
     }
   }
```

Markup:

```
       <SelectionModel>
           <ext:RowSelectionModel runat="server">
               <DirectEvents>
                   <SelectionChange OnEvent="SelectionChange_Event" Success="updateAllWindows()" />
               </DirectEvents>
           </ext:RowSelectionModel>
       </SelectionModel>
```